# Define function arguments as object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Rather than calling functions where the arguments are passed individually, I prefer to pass them as an object so that the order is not important.

e.g.

```
const sum = ({ arg1, arg2, arg3 }) => arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
```

Now I'm migrating some code that I have across, to Typescript and I am unsure how I am supposed to define the interface for such a function.

I've tried something like this and it doesn't work:

[image]

Any clues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
interface InputObj {
    arg1: number;
    arg2: number;
    arg3: number;
}

interface ExampleProps {
    sum: (input: InputObj) => number
}
```

Or inline:

```
interface ExampleProps {
  sum: (
    input: {
      arg1: number;
      arg2: number;
      arg3: number;
    }
  ) => number;
}
```

But depending on your use case you may not need to define `ExampleProps`. Here is your `sum` function without the arbitrary `input` object name:

```
const sum = ({
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
}: {
  arg1: number;
  arg2: number;
  arg3: number;
}) => arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
```

Comment: Thanks @XDgg. Yes, I think that would work, but given that just about everytime I define a function I wrap the arguments up as a single object it will be cumbersome to do define a separate interface for every function. Surely there's a way to define that inline in one interface file?

Comment: Functions are not annotated with interface in typescript. You cannot apply  ExampleProps to sum. Poor design.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to explicitly annotate a function type you can go with:

```js
type Foo = (object: { arg1: number, arg2: number; arg3: number }) => number;

const bar: Foo = ({arg1, arg2, arg3}) =>  arg1 + arg2 + arg3
```

To play around with type annotations and share results I advise [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Foo%20%3D%20(object%3A%20%7B%20arg1%3A%20number%2C%20arg2%3A%20number%3B%20arg3%3A%20number%20%7D)%20%3D%3E%20number%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20bar%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20(%7Barg1%2C%20arg2%2C%20arg3%7D)%20%3D%3E%20%20arg1%20%2B%20arg2%20%2B%20arg3%20) <= check there above :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fully annotated example as function expression:

```js
const sum: ({ 
  arg1, 
  arg2,
  arg3 
}: {
  arg1: number;
  arg2: number;
  arg3: number;
}) => number = ({ arg1, arg2, arg3 }) => arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
```

Here is another and better alternative for arrow functions. Only arguments are annotated and compiler can infer return type correctly. Function has less clutter and works just as before.

```js
const sum = ({ 
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
}: {
  arg1: number;
  arg2: number;
  arg3: number;
}) => arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
```

If you are going to annotate your function in a seperate file:

```js
interface Args {
  arg1: number;
  arg2: number;
  arg3: number;
}

type Sum = (input: Args) => number;
```

```js
const sum: Sum = ({ arg1, arg2, arg3 }) => arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
```

You can use `any` as argument type if argument types are not known. Return type will be inferred as any:

```js
const sum = ({ 
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
}: any) => arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
```

So this one is equivalent to previous example:

```js
const sum: ({ arg1, arg2, arg3 }: any) => any
```

This may not make that much sense for arrow functions but you can set types for known arguments and use key-value pairs for annotating addititional argumens:

```js
const sum = ({ 
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
}: {
  arg1: number;
  arg2: number;
  arg3: number;
  [key: string]: number;
}) => arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
```

You can also use generics:

```js
interface Args {
  arg1: number;
  arg2: number;
  arg3: number;
}

const sum = <T extends Args>({ 
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
}: T) => arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
```

Here is same examples, sum as function statement.

```js
function sum({
  arg1,
  arg2,
  arg3
}: {
  arg1: number;
  arg2: number;
  arg3: number;
}): number {
  return arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
}
```

If you have complicated implementation detail in your function's body, function statement can be better choice for its ergonomics. Plus generics looks less clumsy on function statements.

Answer (score -2):

Have not tried TypeScript. In JavaScript would also consider including default values for the properties of the object to avoid the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property `arg1` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
```

for

```
sum()
```

```js
const sum = ({ arg1, arg2, arg3 }) => 
  arg1 + arg2 + arg3;

try {
  console.log(sum())
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

which can be avoided by setting each value to `0` where the expected parameters and return value is a JavaScript integer

```js
const sum = ({ arg1 = 0, arg2 = 0, arg3 = 0 } = {}) => 
  arg1 + arg2 + arg3;

try {
  console.log(sum()) // 0
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but it doesn't answer my specific question.